# How can I make stop watch in Android?

Tags: android

I am need stop watch like widget in android.Currently I am using Android chronometer,it is not fulfilling my requirements as when I am stopping the chronometer its stops in UI but but it continues to tick in background.

Comment: Altaf, I recommend that you check the events that you generate when you touch the stop button, for instance. Is the event properly handled?  Many of them get lost in the maze when handling events. So please check. :-) Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to stop the chronometer? Just set an internal flag in your widget that you are no longer measuring time.

Take a look at the [related(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526524/android-get-time-of-chronometer-widget) [questions(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324701/android-chronometer-as-a-persistent-stopwatch-how-to-set-starting-time-what-is).