# Android Chronometer

Tags: android, chronometer

How to start the chronometer with a specific time other than default 00:00? Is it possible to set chronometerObj.setBase(startTime) ?

`ch.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()-anylongvalue); 
ch.start();` can I set start time, if I put anylongvalue?

Comment: use CountDownTimer if you want to implement timer functionality. you can start countdown timer with specific Start time.

Answer (score 0):

In general:

> mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - (nr_of_min * 60000 + nr_of_sec * 1000)))

Answer (score 0):

Chronometer object, when instantiated, defaults to the base time being set to now ('now' as in the value you get from `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`).

You can change the base time (00:00 time) by calling `setBase(<some other value>)`.

Presumably, although I haven't tried the experiment, you could see the elapsed time since last system boot using `setBase(0)`.

So you can use chronometer to see the elapsed time since any arbitrary call you made in the past to `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`. The trick is that you need to have stored that value somewhere you can dependably get it back despite app and phone state changes. (See [Android: chronometer as a persistent stopwatch. How to set starting time? What is Chronometer "Base"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2324701/165164) for example.)

Many answers suggest persisting that arbitrary time-in-the-past in an intent. but, at best, this only keeps the timer counting up while the phone stays on.

I already am using a database and store my starting time in there. I created a one-column table for it and store a single record in it. My starting time for the chronometer survives a phone reboot.