# Android Chronometer start with defined value

Tags: android, chronometer

I have an application in which I'm displaying a chronometer to the user for what he's doing.
Whenever the activity goes to the background (wether by home button, or back) I save that time (in seconds) and when the activity is brought back, I want to continue the chronometer running from the same time. The user might select a different item from the list, and the time is different, and also he might turn off the phone...
I can save the time of the chronometer, however I can't set it with a start time.

From the [Chornometer API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.htm), the method `setBase()` states:

> Set the time that the count-up timer is in reference to.

On my understanding, this means that if I set this value to currentTime, it'll start counting with 0.
Now, if I want it to start with the value 17s I thought about setting the base to the currentTime less the time 17 seconds ago. So something like:

```
setBase(system.currentTimeMillis() - (17 * 1000)).
```

However this doesn't work, and the it starts always with 0!

I read a few other threads around here, and none of the answers helped. It always starts with 0!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're going to have to keep track of some time marks yourself.

```
Chronometer myChrono;
long baseTime;
long stopTime;
long elapsedTime;
```

When you set the base time, you want to use:

```
baseTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - stopTime;
myChrono.setBase(baseTime);
```

When you want to see how much time has passed, use:

```
elapsedTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - myChrono.getBase();
```

Take a look at the SystemClock [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime%28%29).

Comment: I was doing some extra code on the onResume and it was overriding the code I was trying on the onCreate method. My bad... Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

```
setBase(system.currentTimeMillis() - (17 * 1000))
```

Should be changed to

```
setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - (17 * 1000))
```

In general:

> mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - (nr_of_min * 60000 + nr_of_sec * 1000)))

Hopefully this will save lots of u folks some time :)

Comment: What if you turn off your phone in the mean time?

Comment: @NunoGonçalves, this is an old post, so presumably you figured this out. But I just worked out a survives-restart solution for myself. So, in case it can help you or someone else, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38546506/165164