# Initialize chronometer with specific time JAVA

Tags: java, android, chronometer

**I have this time in seconds**

( for example seconds = 2796 )

```
long seconds =2796;
long millis = seconds * 1000;
```

So I want my Chronometer to start at 46min 36sec

I tried doing this:

```
chronometer.setBase(myMillis);

long seconds =2796;
long stoptime_millis = seconds * 1000;
long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - stoptime_millis;

customChronometer.setBase(elapsedMillis);
customChronometer.start();
```

But it doesn't work.
with this code my chrono start in 00:00

I tried several approaches but nothing seems to help
for example this one [Android Chronometer start with defined value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477934/android-chronometer-start-with-defined-value)

This is my CustomChronometer

```
public class CustomChronometer extends Chronometer {
    public int msElapsed;
    public boolean isRunning = false;


    public CustomChronometer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomChronometer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CustomChronometer(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public int getMsElapsed() {
        return msElapsed;
    }

    public void setMsElapsed(int ms) {
        setBase(getBase() - ms);
        msElapsed = ms;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - msElapsed);
        isRunning = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        super.stop();
        if (isRunning) {
            msElapsed = (int) (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - this.getBase());
        }
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you call the start() method you are calling setBase again. Your msElapsed is most likely 0 so your are always reseting your Base. In this way the customChronometer.setBase(elapsedMillis); is being ignored.

Comment: Yes @LeandroBorgesFerreira that's right. this is the right answer. You saved my day

Comment: You are welcome =]. I just post my comment as an answer. If you can accept it as the right answer, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the start() method you are calling setBase again. Your msElapsed is most likely 0 so your are always reseting your Base. In this way the customChronometer.setBase(elapsedMillis); is being ignored.

So change your code like this:

```
    @Override public void start() { 
      super.start(); 
//setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - msElapsed); - remove this line.
      isRunning = true; 
}
```