# How do I start chronometer with a specific starting time?

Tags: android, chronometer

Let's say I have this variable:

```
long myMillis = 20000;
```

This means that I want my Chronometer to start at exactly 20 seconds (00:20).

I tried doing this:

```
chronometer.setBase(myMillis);
```

But it doesn't work. It dosn't start with 20 seconds. It starts with some weird time that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Chronometer SetBase in minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788242/android-chronometer-setbase-in-minutes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In general the chronometer works like this (if you would like to set
>   the Base to a specific nr):

```
mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - (nr_of_min * 60000 + nr_of_sec * 1000)))
```

so make it:

```
 mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - (2* 60000 + 0 * 1000)))
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. But I have no idea why it has to be this complicated. If anyone has an explanation, that would be great.

Comment: @Whiz You can read the official documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html

Answer (score 7):

**For Kotlin,**

To start `Chronometer` with starting time 20 seconds, you can use

```
val timeInMilSeconds = 20000
chronometer.base = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - timeInMilSeconds
chronometer.start()
```

This will start Chronometer with starting time 20 seconds i.e. `00:00:20`

Comment: Thanks for the easy and understandable solution.

Answer (score 5):

Its Late but may help others.
I have used following code in first fragment

```
chronometerTimer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
chronometerTimer.start();
```

and then move on some condition to next fragment where chornometer should start at same time of previous chornometer ends, i get elapsed time using this code.

```
long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometerTimer.getBase();
```

and i send elapsedMilis in next fragment and use following code

```
chronometerTimer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - elapsedTime);
chronometerTimer.start();
```

it worked perfectly.