# Multiple timer with Start and Stop button logic

Tags: android, session

I hope you All understand with my case. For example, I have 3 food to cook :

```
{
"response": [{
        "food": "burger"
    },
    {
        "food": "pizza"
    },
    {
        "food": "potato fried"
    }]
```

}

I put the `food` in a List. When one food click, there will another `Activity`. In this `Activity` there are two button `Start` and `Stop`. I want to know :

- How to handle *every* `Stop` button cannot click until `Start` button clicked. **But** when the App let say `Force Stop` manually by user, the session of Buttons still there.

I have many many many `Food` in my App and I think to save the Session in `Shared Preference` will take more effort. Is there any way to do this? Or `Shared Preferences` is a must in my case? I need an Advice the way which better for my App perfomance. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I use `Shared Preferences` to handle the timer and session. First, I keep the `lasttime` and save it into `Shared Preference` if let say current timer activity is close (burger activity). When the last record click again (burger activity), I get the `lasttime` value from `Shared Preference` and I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133592/how-do-i-start-chronometer-with-a-specific-starting-time) to start again the timer. From it, I can check if `lasttime` available, activity will show the start button only or vice versa for stop button.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SQLite` database to do your task. Now for managing session for button for each food, Create a table say `FOOD_TABLE` and add column like: `ID, NAME, STATUS` so when fetch data from API store all data in your `sqlite` DB table
in that set `STATUS` value to zero, when you click on `start button` for a particular food, update `STATUS` to 1 via `update query`, when you stop it update again `STATUS` to 0.

Comment: How if my list refreshed? I have a refresh button on my list

Comment: If a list is refreshed all data will be wiped out you have to get them from API,
another approach is you can get all data from sqlite which have the state maintained via STATUS column, it up to you what you want.

Comment: how if user clear data?In my knowledge, sqlite will create a file into internal memory device `.db` right?

Comment: Yes but clearing data means you are resetting app like fresh install, so even if user logged in, will be logout immediately and also app killed automatically when you click on clear data.So you don't have to worry about clear data