# Showing Hours in Chronometer

Tags: android, chronometer

How do you show hours in chronometer.By default its format is (hh:mm:ss), doesn't show in the view.I need it to show like 00:00:00 , and update the time.
I also require to pause the time and resume the time.

Comment: This answer by sushildlh seems to be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237947/chronometer-with-hmmss/38238363#38238363

Answer (score 0):

You must have to see at [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html) to see how to use format for Chronometer.
[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324701/android-chronometer-as-a-persistent-stopwatch-how-to-set-starting-time-what-i?rq=1) could also help you to see an implementation of a chronometer.