# Chronometer with H:MM:SS

Tags: java, android

How to display Chronometer with H:MM:SS? I read MM:SS and H:MM:SS are displaying by default.I found only for MM:SS.

Here is my code for MM:SS with start and stop button.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button start,stop;
Chronometer chrono;
long time;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    chrono = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

 start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());


            chrono.start();
        }
    });

    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            chrono.stop();

        }
    });


}

}
```

here is my xml code for MainActivity:

```
    <Chronometer
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/chronometer"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start"
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Stop"
    android:id="@+id/stop"
    android:layout_below="@+id/start"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Chronometer with H:MM:SS

Divide the time into **minute , hour and second** using **setOnChronometerTickListener.**

use this ......

```
Chronometer chrono  = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronomete);
chrono.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener(){
        @Override
            public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
            long time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
            int h   = (int)(time /3600000);
            int m = (int)(time - h*3600000)/60000;
            int s= (int)(time - h*3600000- m*60000)/1000 ;
            String t = (h < 10 ? "0"+h: h)+":"+(m < 10 ? "0"+m: m)+":"+ (s < 10 ? "0"+s: s);
            chronometer.setText(t);
        }
    });
    chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    chrono.setText("00:00:00");
```

[image: output]

**EDIT**

**For Start**

Declare globally a long variable `timeWhenStopped` . It is **maintain** the time .

```
private long timeWhenStopped = 0;
```

**Start Listener...**  get the timeWhenStopped and start from there.

```
 start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + timeWhenStopped);
            chrono.start();
        }
    });
```

**Stop Listener....**  store the time in timeWhenStopped and stop.

```
stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            timeWhenStopped = chrono.getBase() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            chrono.stop();

        }
    });
```

enjoy coding............

Comment: Thanks for your code. Could you tell me to use it with button click Start and stop function?

Comment: Its working.But i have to use separate button to start and stop.

Comment: Is it working ? If not that have look on edit answer...I am doing some changes ..........

Comment: ohhh thanks. plz edit your code. i did the things what u said but it shows initially 00:00 only. and before clicking start it automatically started to count.

Comment: go through the edit and let me know , If there any problem .

Comment: after clicking start only the pattern is changing to 00:00:00 initially it shows 00:00. I used chrono.setYText("00:00:00"); its not working

Comment: why you using this `chrono.setYText("00:00:00");` ??

Comment: Sorry typing mistake. chrono.setText("00:00:00); its not working so i have to use format in xml.is it correct?

Comment: there no need to set text in the Chronometer . When it start it's automatically start from 00:00:00 .

Comment: But i want to show 00:00:00 not 00:00 when opening the app.

Comment: set text after this line ....`chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());` like this `chrono.setText("00:00:00");`

Comment: where i have to write ? after defining the id for chrono??

Comment: no after this line `chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());` **OR** see my answer ....

Comment: Its working like that only. initially opening the app it showing like 00:00 after clicking start only it moves to 00:00:00 :( sorry i'm asking more doubt

Comment: I have a solution for you . Please use single button to start and stop .... That solve you problem ...... **OR** you have to use custom Chronometer. If you wanted single button let me know .....

Comment: but clicking start again show 00:00 next second only it moves 00:00:00 .did u get my question ??

Comment: hi at last i found one way in xml inside chronometer    android:format="00:00:00"   .it shows 00:00:00 while opening the app. thanks for your help. today i feel really happy because your code. shall i ask my last doubt?

Comment: sure what is that  ??

Comment: after stop button when i click start,it starts to count from where time stopped. I want it start from 00:00:00

Comment: remove `timeWhenStopped` variable .... and in start button make it  `chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime())` like that .

Answer (score 0):

layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_data"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/chronometer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_data"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

In activity

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tvData;
    Chronometer chronometer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_data);
        chronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

        startChronometer();

        chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener() {
            public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer cArg) {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, getCurrentMiliSecondsOfChronometer());
                tvData.setText(DateFormat.format("HH:mm:ss", calendar.getTime()));
            }
        });
    }

    private int getCurrentMiliSecondsOfChronometer() {
        int stoppedMilliseconds = 0;
        String chronoText = chronometer.getText().toString();
        String array[] = chronoText.split(":");
        if (array.length == 2) {
            stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 1000 + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 1000;
        } else if (array.length == 3) {
            stoppedMilliseconds =
                    Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 60 * 1000 + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 60 * 1000
                            + Integer.parseInt(array[2]) * 1000;
        }
        return stoppedMilliseconds;
    }

    private void startChronometer() {
        int stoppedMilliseconds = getCurrentMiliSecondsOfChronometer();
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - stoppedMilliseconds);
        chronometer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no TextView in your xml code. :( . I'm beginner so plz Explain me completely.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set with attractive **Chronometer** format like **00 hrs : 00 min : 00 sec**

```
        chronometer.setText("00 hrs : 00 min : 00 sec");
        chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
                CharSequence text = chronometer.getText();
                if (text.length() == 5) {
                    String a[] = text.toString().split(":");
                    String min = a[0] + " min : ";
                    String sec = a[1] + " sec";
                    chronometer.setText("00 hrs : " + min + sec);
                } else if (text.length() == 7) {
                    String a[] = text.toString().split(":");
                    String hr = a[0] + " hrs : ";
                    String min = a[1] + " min : ";
                    String sec = a[2] + " sec";
                    chronometer.setText("0" + hr + min + sec);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this logic

```
 long countUp = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase()) / 1000;
 long sec = countUp % 60;
 long temp=countUp / 60;
 long mins = (temp)%60;
 long hrs = temp / 60;
```