# Chronometer widget starts from 01.00.00

Tags: java, android, chronometer

when I launch my app from the emulator the Chronometer starts at 00.00.00, but when I launch it from a smartphone it starts one hour ahead (01.00.00). 
This is my code for starting the chronometer:

```
chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
chronometer.start();
```

Of course the problem is when I get the SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), I've read the documentation but cannot find something to face this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved manually adding the time in my chronometer, as suggested here:

[Chronometer with H:MM:SS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237947/chronometer-with-hmmss/38238363)