# Timer display to countdown

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer

right now I have my timer displaying seconds, what can I add to it to display the time in a 0:00 format?

```
new CountDownTimer((300 * 1000), 1000) {

                         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                             mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                         }

                         public void onFinish() {
                             mTextField.setText("Session Completed!");
                         }
                      }.start();
```

Comment: use a chronometer widget

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526524/android-get-time-of-chronometer-widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Date date = new Date((300 * 1000)* 1000);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String dateFormatted = formatter.format(date);
```

You can also use

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
```

Comment: Im a bit confused, can you apply that into the countdowntimer I posted at the start? thanks a lot!

Comment: Nop, if you are interested in using CountdownTimer only then you have to use millisecond format only, but if you want to show a textview then inside the tick you are having the parameter millisUntilFinished, place that inside the date instead of (300*1000)*1000.....Please upvote and accept my answer if you got what you wanted

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
 long temp_long = millisUntilFinished / 1000;

 second = temp_long % 60;
 hour = temp_long / 3600;
 minute = (temp_long / 60) % 60;
 String tempTimer;

 tempTimer = ((hour < 10) ? "0" + hour : "" + hour)+ ((minute < 10) ? ":0" + minute : ":"+ minute)+ ((second < 10) ? ":0" + second : ":" + second);

 mTextField.setText(tempTimer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use android Chronometer to display countdown.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
val min: Long = millisUntilFinished / 1000 / 60

val sec: Long = millisUntilFinished / 1000 % 60

if (sec < 10) {
     binding?.value?.text = "0$min:0$sec"
} else {
     binding?.value.text =" 0$min:$sec"
}
```