# Android chronometer counting in characters instead of numbers

Tags: java, android, date, chronometer

I have a chronometer which I set in the following way:

```
long realTime =  SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
long time = alert.Created.getTime();
holder.timeChronometer.setBase(realTime - time);
holder.timeChronometer.start();

//alert.Created is a Date type, it's value is Thu Oct 30 12:41:45 CST 2014
```

The problem is that the chronometer doesn't count entirely in numbers, it counts in characters.

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/a/526604/1737819 ?:)

Comment: Yes, but is keeps the same, I want that the chronometer set time in hours:minutes:seconds format with the time of that date minus the elapsedTime, but still gives me counting in characters instead of numbers :/