# How to set Timer when button clicked?

Tags: java, android, timer

I mean is like stopwach, when button clicked the Timer is on until the stop button pressed

```
startbutton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.black1);
  startbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

              public void onClick(View v){
              //Start the timer
                                         }                
            });

 stopbutton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.black1);
 stopbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

              public void onClick(View v){
              //Stop the timer
                                         }                
            });
```

and second question,

if timer show 90 second how to make it show imageview or button in screen? like some if statement to make button visible each timer count to 90 second (90, 180, 270, etc..) he will set button visibility to visible.

Thanks before.

Comment: please check out the following link:http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/handler/android-timer-example/

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: Thanks for give some link guy's it helped but still not answer my second question in there

Comment: Check out : http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener.html or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526524/android-get-time-of-chronometer-widget

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use chronometer in your `xml`

```
<Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/chronometer1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Chronometer" />
```

in your `java`

```
Chronometer focus = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);

startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        focus.start();
        setVisibilityTimerOn(); //Second Question Solution
    }
});

stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        focus.stop();
        setVisibilityTimerOff();
    }
});
```

**Second Question** If you want to turn VISIBILITY on/off of some button/ImageView set up a handler

```
//Declare these variable 
private Handler handler;
private Runnable updateView;


private void setVisibilityTimerOn(){
     timeHandler = new Handler(); //it's better if you declare this line in onCreate (becuase if user press stopButton first before pressing startButton error will occur as handler was never initialized and you try calling removeCallback function)
     updateView = new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
              someImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }
     };
     handler.postDelayed(updateView ,90000);//this will be on after 90 second
}

private void setVisibilityTimerOff(){
    handler.removeCallbacks(updateView);
}
```

Comment: yeah it's good but still not answering my second question in there L-X

Comment: I didn't understand your second question , can you elaborate ?

Comment: i mean is like this, if the Timer already 90 second then make like some if statement to set button visibility. it is possible to do like that?

Comment: Always happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

This works like stop watch timer with the interval of 1ms.

```
    Handler handler= new Handler();

1. click to start   (code)


  Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
        //put your code to be executed on within every interval
                           handler.postDelayed(this, 1); 
                       }
                    };

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5); //start after 5 seconds 

 2. click to stop (code)
     handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

It should work.
        Thanks