# How to get elapsed time from chronometer in form of int

Tags: java, android

I have a chronometer and am using `mChronometer.getText();`how do I convert this to an int? using `Integer.parseInt();` throws an error because `mChronometer.getText();` outputs in the form minutes : seconds

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you are using `android.widget.Chronometer` you can get the elapsed time with :

```
int elapsedMillis = (int) (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mChronometer.getBase());
```

Comment: where would i put this in my code? after mChronometer.start of before

Comment: refer to this post for more informations how to implement `android.widget.Chronometer` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526524/android-get-time-of-chronometer-widget