# Getting the time of a Chronometer in a String?

Tags: android, string, chronometer

I want to get the time of the Chronometer into a String (or is a string wrong for this kind of use?).

How does it work?

```
Chronometer mChronometer;
Button button1;
Button button2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            mChronometer.start();
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mChronometer.stop();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526524/android-get-time-of-chronometer-widget
Can you find your answer in that?

Comment: Not very much, but thx anyway. I´ve already got a good answer!

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't know you were looking for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the elapsed time in int,

```
int elapsed = (int)(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()-mChronometer.getBase());
```

convert it to string and then set the text in textview

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(elapsed));
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! How can I now divide the number e.g. by 3 before showing it in the TextView?

Comment: @Niggo Simply try `textView.setText(String.valueOf(elapsed/3));`

Comment: Ok, thank youuu. Too easy to think about ;-D. Will try it tomorrow